# How to create UDF for multi-variable Index Match formula

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match, user-defined-functions

I want to create a UDF for the following Excel index-match formula:

```
{=INDEX($A$1:$J$7,MATCH(B9,$A$1:$A$7,0),MATCH(1,($A$1:$J$1=B10)*($A$2:$J$2=B11),0))}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q07fw.png)

```
    AA  AA  AA  BB  BB  BB  CC  CC  CC
    a   b   c   a   b   c   a   b   c
1   10  55  24  48  95  19  5   28  65
2   16  48  3   62  46  50  59  80  17
3   63  47  19  23  67  26  14  16  9
4   55  91  4   55  72  79  27  39  50
5   75  53  7   42  45  19  58  41  12

Condition1  3                               
Condition2  AA                              
Condition3  c                               

index-Match 19  =INDEX($A$1:$J$7,MATCH(B9,$A$1:$A$7,0),MATCH(1,($A$1:$J$1=B10)*($A$2:$J$2=B11),0))}
```

NOTE: `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER` to return array result in excel

This works in an excel worksheet, but when I try to convert it to VBA, I get an error.

I figure I need to apply FormulaArray somewhere within following codes, any help is greatly appreciated.

I have tried with following codes but got #VALUE!

```
Public Function UDF_IndexMatch(Condition1, Condition2, COndition3)
    UDF_IndexMatch = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("$A$1:$J$7"), _
                                                  Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Condition1, Range("$A$1:$A$7"), 0), _ 
                                                 Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(1, (Range("$A$1:$J$1") = Condition2) * (Range("$A$2:$J$2") = COndition3), 0))

End Function
```

the end result should be something like this:

```
= UDF_IndexMatch(Condition1, Condition2, COndition3)
```

return: corresponding index match result

Comment: Is it always `"$A$1:$J$7"` or do you need the ability for the user to set the range also?

Comment: @ScottCraner eventually i will create another parameter for table/range selection, but for now just to get the formula working, "$A$1:$J$7", is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have misread your post at first and thought you would be better of with a standard formula, however you are specifically looking for a UDF. Just for the sake of giving other options, here is one:

```
Public Function ReturnVal(RNG As Range, Con1, Con2, Con3) As String
Dim SearchRng1 As String, SearchRng2 As String, SearchRng3 As String, SearchRng4 As String

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(RNG.Parent.Name)
    SearchRng1 = RNG.Parent.Name & "!" & RNG.Range(.Cells(3, 2), .Cells(RNG.Rows.Count, RNG.Columns.Count)).Address(False, False)
    SearchRng2 = RNG.Parent.Name & "!" & RNG.Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(RNG.Rows.Count, 1)).Address(False, False)
    SearchRng3 = RNG.Parent.Name & "!" & RNG.Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(1, RNG.Columns.Count)).Address(False, False)
    SearchRng4 = RNG.Parent.Name & "!" & RNG.Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(2, RNG.Columns.Count)).Address(False, False)
End With
ReturnVal = Evaluate("=INDEX(" & SearchRng1 & ",MATCH(" & Con1 & "," & SearchRng2 & ",0),MATCH(""" & Con2 & """&""" & Con3 & """," & SearchRng3 & "&" & SearchRng4 & ",0))")

End Function
```

As long as you select the range in variables, it doesn't matter where your table is positioned or how big it is. You may also call it from another worksheet.

[image]

Comment: thank you @JvdV this works out great, only thing i made change to was Dim SearchRng4 As String instead of Double.

Comment: Yes that was my bad, should have been string

Comment: do you have any recommendations to make this UDF work when RNG is selected from a different worksheet within the workbook?

Comment: @SteveC, see my recommendation in edited answer to use the `Parent.Name` property.

Comment: thank you for your help. For some reason your code didn't work for me, but i updated it a little, and it's now working perfectly as i wanted. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can just save the data in a variant array and iterate that:

```
Public Function UDF_IndexMatch(Condition1, Condition2, COndition3)
    Application.Volatile

    Dim rngarr As Variant
    rngarr = Application.Caller.Parent.Range("A1:J7").Value

    Dim irow As Long
    irow = 0

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(rngarr, 1) To UBound(rngarr, 1)
        If rngarr(i, 1) = Condition1 Then
            irow = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    Dim jcolumn As Long
    jcolumn = 0

    If irow > 0 Then
        Dim j As Long
        For j = LBound(rngarr, 2) To UBound(rngarr, 2)
            If rngarr(1, j) = Condition2 And rngarr(2, j) = COndition3 Then
                jcolumn = j
            End If
        Next j
    End If

    If j > 0 Then

        UDF_IndexMatch = rngarr(irow, jcolumn)
    End If
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: I was hoping there is a way to do it without iterating through the array, but this works just fine, Thank you very much. @ScottCraner

Comment: Don't forget to make it Volatile - it references data that is not part of the parameters