# Converting Excel INDEX, MATCH, VBLOOKUP To VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following excel formula

```
{=INDEX(config!H2:H20,
MATCH(1,
(F2=config!F2:F20)*(VLOOKUP(D2,config!C2:D20,2,FALSE)=config!G2:G20),0))}
```

In VBA how would I write something with multiple conditions? is this possible using VBA?

Comment: you would do something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55711753/how-to-create-udf-for-multi-variable-index-match-formula/55712127#55712127

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Const FRM = "INDEX(config!H2:H20,MATCH(1,(F<#>=config!F2:F20)*" & _
            "(VLOOKUP(D<#>,config!C2:D20,2,FALSE)=config!G2:G20),0))"

Dim res, sht as WorkSheet, rw as Long

Set sht = activesheet
rw = 2

res = sht.Evaluate(Replace(FRM, "<#>", rw)) 'use Evaluate in the context of the correct sheet
                                            '   (parent of D2, F2 in this case)
```